# Google Play Services Library and API 18 (AppOpsManager not found)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I use Google Play Services and selectively compile in Gradle for Admob and Analytics like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
    ...
}
```

It doesn't work on API 18 device. It crashed with error log:

```
Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
```

I then upgraded my device to API 19, and it worked. So I guess the latest Google Play Service Library 7.8.0, is referencing AppOpsManager, but according to documentation of AppOpsManager ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html)), it's only available since API 19.

Any hints to get it to work with lower API level devices?

(I have to use selective compile for Google Play Service to avoid "dex-index-overflow", and I'm using Dexguard which doesn't work with multi-dex enabled apk.)

Comment: I have the samme issue. Using google play services '7.8.0' with analytics and app-indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob and Analytics works from API 9

Try with this:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'